# Can we configure the Eclipse TFS plugin to require a work item on check in?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

When we check in a file, we would like to have the plugin not allow check-in unless a work order(s) has been specified. I've looked for that before but haven't found a way. I'm looking in Preferences > Team > Team Foundation Server and don't see anything there.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed you are using Team Explorer Everywhere. What you are looking for is check-in policy. You need to add **Work Item Policy** if you want to require that one or more work items is associated with each changeset.

[image]

Check following link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/gg475890(v=vs.100)

Comment: And the Eclipse TFS plugin will honor that and require a work item?

Comment: Yes. But notice Check-in policies that you define by using Team Explorer Everywhere only apply when you check in by using the Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse or the Cross-platform Command-Line Client for Team Foundation Server. If you use another client, such as Team Web Access or Team Explorer in Visual Studio, these policies do not apply.